# MobX: how to change an observable value in response to another value's change?

Tags: javascript, mobx

Say I have an object with two MobX `@observable` fields:

```
class Address {
  @observable country
  @observable city
}
```

When one of them changes, I want to call a function that changes the other one. For example, when `country` changes, I might want to clear `city` if its value isn't valid for the new country.

Is there a good pattern for this?

I don't think I can use `autorun`. Since I'm trying to change an observable value, and I have `enforceActions` turned on, I need to change it in an `action`. But this throws an error "Autorun does not accept actions since actions are untrackable":

```
autorun(action(() => {
    if (this.country === 'US' && this.city === 'Paris') this.city = '';
}));
```

I know I can add a `@computed` function that returns either `city` or a new value. But then the original value of `city` is still there, and will get returned when `country` changes back. I don't want this; I want to permanently change `city`.

```
@computed get realCity() {
    if (this.country === 'US' && this.city === 'Paris') return '';
    return this.city;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [observe](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/observe.html) to observe the object in the constructor, and reset the city if the country changed.

**Example ([JSBin](http://jsbin.com/weqiyuwaka/1/edit?js,console))**

```
class Address {
  @observable country = 'Sweden';
  @observable city = 'Stockholm';

  constructor() {
    observe(this, (change) => {
      if (change.name === 'country') {
        // Put your logic for changing the city here
        this.city = '';
      }
    });
  }
}

const address = new Address();

console.log(`${address.country}, ${address.city}`);
address.country = 'Spain';
console.log(`${address.country}, ${address.city}`);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should look at your problem with a different angle.

The thing I am asking myself is: isn't there something you could do to avoid the problem you face altogether?

Why allow the situation to happen in the first place?

- If a country is set: create a subset of cities for that country.
- If a city is set and the country changes, unset the city at the same time.

Regarding mobx specific patterns this bit of docs is useful:

> As a rule of thumb: use autorun if you have a function that should run automatically but that doesn't result in a new value. Use computed for everything else. Autoruns are about initiating effects, not about producing new values. 
>   [Mobx docs](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html)

Answer (score 1):

This task can be done via the "when" process initialized in the store constructor:

```
class store(){
    constructor(){
     when (){
      ()=>{(this.country === 'US' && this.city === 'Paris')}
      ()=>{ this.city = ''}
    } 
  }
}
```

A full and well documented explanation can be found here:
https://mobx.js.org/refguide/when.html

Comment: I haven't used mobx.when yet, but as far as I know, `when` will run only once. Maybe it's `reaction` or `observe` you had in mind, if you want this effect to occur every time it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
observe(state, "country", ({ oldValue, newValue }) => this.handleCountryChange(oldValue, newValue));


handleCountryChange = (oldValue, newValue) => {}
```